# Should I use HiddenFor for all data entity properties I'm not editing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I had an issue where a Modified Date was being reset to some default on my edit post. It seems like the model binder ignores properties that are not part of the view. As soon as i add the @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModifiedDate) then the original value is included in the object passed into the post action.

I would have thought all property values would persist through this process but this doesn't seem the case. I'm using a sql database for my models and in the current context some fields are not available for editing. Does this mean i should use HiddenFor for all properties that are not editable to ensure the integrity of the original data?

If so is there a way to ensure new fields added will be automatically be included?

an example of the post method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Customer customer)
    {
        //Some code here
    }
```

And the view

```
@model MyApp.Models.Customer
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<h2>
    Edit</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 <fieldset>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModifiedData)
    @*Some other fields*@
 </fieldset>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

MVC only posts elements within the Form. It uses standard HTTP post methodology, unlike ASP.Net that holds values in a ViewState (this is effectively held in the form as a hidden element as well but you never really see it). So yes if you want a value to persist you must store it in the form.

The advantage of this over ASP.Net is you have complete control over what is passed backwards and forwards in your HTTP, so no more gigantic ViewState passed all over the place, 90% of which you probably never use. In this way you can tune the data sent across the wire in a way you never could in ASP.Net.

No there is no way to ensure that hidden elements are populated. You need to do this yourself. Again, this is because the form is stateless, like a proper web site should be!

You could use session, though I wouldn't recommend it.